# How to trigger a broadcast event manually

Tags: android, android-widget

Everyone
This is a question about how to creating a widget in my application. We all know how to add our widgets by customizing AppWidgetProvider. And the adding action is as follows:

System Menu -> Widget -> Widget Item(Our Widget Name)

However, what I want is to gain the same effects by just clicking one button, e.g. 'Add Widget', in my application. The first thought coming into my brain is to trigger a broadcast event of adding widget in the handler function of the 'Add Widget' button. But I don't how to trigger a broadcast event manually.

Guys, any ideas will be appreciated.

Wishes

Jhfu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by Android, sorry.

To be more specific, applications that are not home screens cannot add app widgets to home screens.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your reply. Hope to be supported some day

Answer (score 1):

`Context.sendBroadcast(Intent intent)`

Comment: While this is how you broadcast Intents, the OP will not be able to use this to achieve the desired objective.

Comment: If the intent object could be constructed correctly, then it should work. Is that right?

Comment: @machinarium:  that is what i thought but not having looked into it, i would bow to Commonsware experience.